# How to use POST method with jQuery v1.11.4 tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I'm trying to upgrade jquery ui from 1.9.2 to jquery ui 1.11.4 and I've discovered that ajaxOptions has been removed form the tabs control. I've been using:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    ajaxOptions: {
    error: (function (x, y, z) { AjaxError(x, y, z) }),
    data: { somefield: $("#somefield").val() },
    type: 'POST'
    }
 });
```

I've changed the code to:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    beforeLoad: function (event, ui) {
        ui.ajaxSettings.method = 'POST';
        ui.ajaxSettings.error = function (x, y, z) { AjaxError(x, y, z) };
        ui.ajaxSettings.url += "?somefield=" + $("#somefield").val();
    }
});
```

However the ui.ajaxSettings.method cannot be changed at this point. The API documentation states :

> The data will need to be processed prior to the beforeLoad. From the
>   API documentation: Note: Although ui.ajaxSettings is provided and can
>   be modified, some of these settings have already been processed by
>   jQuery. For example, prefilters have been applied, data has been
>   processed, and type has been determined. The beforeLoad event occurs
>   at the same time, and therefore has the same restrictions, as the
>   beforeSend callback from jQuery.ajax().

But how can I change the method to POST?

Comment: Previous code no longer works under 1.11.4 as the ajaxOptions has been removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if that helps

`

```
beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
   ui.ajaxSettings.type = 'POST'; 
   ui.ajaxSettings.hasContent = true;
   ui.jqXHR.setRequestHeader( "Content-Type", ui.ajaxSettings.contentType );
   ui.ajaxSettings.data = jQuery.param( { foo: 'bar'}, ui.ajaxSettings.traditional );
}
```

`

ref: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8673

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `beforeLoad`, try using the following:

```
var tabData = {};
$("#tabs").tabs({
    // select data in the tab
    select: function(event, ui) {
        tabData = {
            data: $('#yourData').serialize();
        };
    },
    ajaxOptions: {
        type: 'POST',
        data: tabData,
        error: function(x, y, z) { AjaxError(x, y, z) }
    }
});
```

The `select` method is used to grab data from the active tab.

Comment: its an old syntax pre 1.9

Answer (score 0):

No doubt this is not the most elegant solution, but after trying a number of suggestions to fix this (and none of them working), I tried a different approach.  Basically, instead of using the built-in AJAX functions (beforeLoad, load), I set up the tabs as if they were pre-loaded, then use the activate event to load the tab data.

HTML:

```
<div id='tabs'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#tab1'>Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab2'>Tab 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id='tab1'><p>Loading...</p></div>
  <div id='tab2'><p>Loading...</p></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery("#tabs").tabs({
    active: 0,
    activate: function(event, ui) {
        var active = jQuery("#tabs").tabs("option","active");
        switch (active) {
          case 0:
            LoadTab0(ui.newPanel);
            break;
          case 1:
            LoadTab1(ui.newPanel);
            break;
        }
    },
    create: function(event, ui) {
        LoadTab0(ui.panel);
    }
});

function LoadTab0(panel) {
  var args = {
    // data to post here
  };
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: args
  })
    .done(function(result) {
        panel.html(result);
    });
}

function LoadTab1(panel) {
  var args = {
    // data to post here
  };
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: args
  })
    .done(function(result) {
        panel.html(result);
    });
}
```

The jQuery UI documentation states: "Since the activate event is only fired on tab activation, it is not fired for the initial tab when the tabs widget is created. If you need a hook for widget creation use the create event."  Therefore you have to use the create event and just call the function corresponding to the `active` option that you set (in the example it is 0).